# TLS inspection with proxy

Tags: tls, networking, certificate-authority, proxy

How can I install a proxy in my network to be able decrypt any traffic that passes through my network? I own all devices, and if there is a need I can provide the private keys and certificates for the proxy to decrypt packets. I want to know is this possible or should I get NGFW to do this job?

Comment: [Github](https://github.com/search?q=tls+interception+proxy&ref=opensearch) shows a  number of implementations for you to try.

Comment: Note that many TLS intercepting proxies have known security problems and can often be configured insecurely, so intercepting all the data can significantly harm security.  I wouldn't recommend this configuration in an environment with multiple users.

Comment: Given that the OP is aware of that products which do this exist, this question looks like a product recommendation to me (no matter if commercial or not). Such recommendations are off-topic. But in short: TLS interception can be done with the squid proxy and there are likely other free products too. What you than actually do with the intercepted traffic is another matter (and not specified apart from broadly saying "inspection"), i.e. decryption capability alone does not protect against anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you will run into a few problems.

The basic setup would require a a proxy which will automatically generate TLS certificates for all websites visited by the end points. You can add the root CA used by this proxy to all endpoints, which will then accept the certificates issued by the proxy.

There are some practical problems with that:

- Built-in certificates: modern browsers, for big websites have built-in constraints on which certificates are valid for these websites. Even if you have a "technically valid" certificate, Google Chrome will still issue a warning if you try to use an alternative certificate for Google.com or YouTube, just because it's built-in to the browser
- Public Key Pinning/Certificate Pinning: On the first request; a webserver can send a HTTP header to pin the certificate in the local browser validation mechanism to the current certificate or the current issuer. This will prevent the mechanism above from working, because the issuer will change once you put the proxy in place.
- EV Certificates: as of now, without recompiling a browser, there is no way to "fake" Extended Validation certificates (the ones which give you a green checkmark in the browser). The EV CA's are built-in to the browsers and cannot be manually added by the user.
- CAA DNS Records: CAA DNS records register for a domain which issuers are valid. It will prevent modern webbrowsers from accepting certificates which might be X509 "valid", but are not issued by the certificate authority in the CAA record.

For example: `mtak.nl` has the following CAA:

```
mtak@rubiks~$ dig -t caa mtak.nl +short
0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
```

If you would run traffic to `mtak.nl` through your proxy, even if it issues a valid certificate, the browser would still reject it because that certificate was not issued by Let's Encrypt.

Possibly these additional checks can be disabled in webbrowsers, but you will face quite a lot of hurdles in getting this to work smoothly. Additionally, as browser developers are fixing the "gaps" in SSL/TLS, these checks will become more and more strict over time.

A good think to think about: as an academic exercise this is very cool, but in practice I trust my bank more to secure connections than I do myself (especially in a permanent setup). I don't have a Security Operations Center watching firewalls and WAFs, looking out for zero-days, doing the updates and all stuff that comes with good and secure IT operations. So be mindful of what you do and how it impacts you, and keep reassessing over time if it's worth the risk.